# Storing public data for multiple access

Tags: java

I currently work on a project where a DB receives simultaneous CRUD operations from multiple clients. The middle-tier will be a restful webservice written in java.
The DB stores products from a warehouse. Each product has its own datasheet (pdf file).

I would like to ask:

1) Where to save the pdf file? Is the best to let the user upload it to web-service and the web-service store it in its filesystem?

2) I want the user to be able to backup/restore db data. This will be in a .sql backup file. If my assumption in the previous question is correct then this applies here too? Or let the user store the backup file in his PC filesystem? What is best?

Comment: You're asking about at least three different things here; where to store generated information, where to store backups, and the best practices for the former.  There's a lot of answers here and they're going to be pretty much all over the board (and there really isn't a single answer for "best practices").

Comment: The answer also depends on what sort of scale (requests and data) you're expected to handle. At some point, most people just start storing static files like your pdfs in Amazon S3, but this doesn't make sense for 15 files and 10 users.

Comment: Upload to a browseable inaccessible filesystem, preferably with versioning (old timestamped versions in an archive directory). For undermore legal accountability product sheets must be kept for ages. Make it as user-friendly as possible, as departments loose control of their own responsibilities. Or integrate a Document Management System.